# Cannot access to my datsbase when running the server as a service

Tags: mongodb

I have recently installed Mongodb on my ubuntu machine according to the linux manual in mongodb website. everything looks ok when i run the command "mongod" to start a mongodb server.when I try to run

> sudo service mongod start

it says that mongod start/running, proccess 3369

but when I try to access the database from the Mongodb GUI it cannot acces it. nor from the chrome itself using the port 27017.

how can i fix this?

Comment: try from terminal using mongoshell

Comment: please show us what error its reporting

Comment: try this first stop your running mongo service like   `sudo service mongodb stop` and then start your mongo server using `mongod` so your mongo server will start then go to new terminal/tab and type mongod hope your mongo will start

Comment: there is no error. when i start the service it says: "mongod start/running, proccess 3369". yogesh - you're method isn't working it return error when i type mongod the second time since the server is alredy running in the other terminal...

Comment: @user2221776: Please have a look at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` (or whatever is used as a log file destination in `mongod.conf`. It is very likely that there is an error. Please add that error and the subsequent lines (and maybe some lines before) to your question by editing it.